# Applying a role if users do not have other roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Users are still getting the public role regardless of the role they have

I'm sorry if the answer here is fairly obvious but I'm learning javascript as I write this bot. I'm aiming for users to be able to do !name  and gain a role called "public" as long as they don't have a role listed in the code (General, Captain, etc.).

```
client.on('message', async message => {
if (message.channel.id === '535226845654810624'); {
    if(message.content.startsWith('!name')) {
        if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'General', 'Captain', 'Lieutenant', 'Sergeant', 'Corporal', 'Recruit'));
        const newname = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        message.member.setNickname(newname);
    }

    else {(message.content.startsWith('!name'));} {
        if(message.channel.id === '535226845654810624') {
            const newname = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
            message.member.setNickname(newname);
            const newrole = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === 'Public');
            message.member.addRole(newrole);
            message.delete();
        }
    }
```

I'm sure the code is completely ugly. I'm still learning. Right now regardless of if they have the Gen/Capt/Lieutenant/etc roles they still gain the public role.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
if(message.channel.id === '535226845654810624') {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!name')) {
        const newname = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        message.member.setNickname(newname);
        const newrole = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === 'Public');
        message.member.addRole(newrole);
        message.delete();
    }
}
```

This is the code I had before adding in the attempt to ignore the role add if they have the other roles. I'm not sure how to change this to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code, give it a try and let me know what the result is. There were several errors with your code which I'm quite surprised your editor didn't pick up (or atleast didn't error out the code), such as having a semicolon right after defining an `if` statement, the extra curly brackets after your `else` statement, etc.

Anyway, the code below checks if the command entered is `!name` and if so, it assigns the new nickname to the user. After that it checks if the user has any of the specified roles, and if he does not, he gets a new role 'Public'.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.id === '535226845654810624') {
    if(message.content.startsWith('!name')) {

      // Users are allowed to change their nicknames no matter their roles
      const newname = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
      message.member.setNickname(newname);

      // Define the roles which need to be checked
      const roleNames = ['General', 'Captain', 'Lieutenant', 'Sergeant', 'Corporal', 'Recruit'];

      // If the user does not have any of the roles above, assign them the role 'Public'
      if (!message.member.roles.some(role => roleNames.includes(role.name))) {
        const newrole = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === 'Public');
        message.member.addRole(newrole);
        message.delete();
      }
    }
  }
});
```